# Cloud SQL instance Storage used unconvincingly large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I created couple of cloudsql instance, the size is growing on its own. The size of a fresh instance is 250MB. It doesn't seem normal.

what is going wrong here ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the fact that the console shows that storage used = 0.1% of 250GB i.e. 250MB.

If you hover over the question mark in the column header, it indicates that the storage actually used is the size of your DB *plus* some additional amount for the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Yes that answered, Thanks @jarmod

Comment: Hi Rama, if one of the provided responses answered your question then please accept that as the answer to help future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using InnoDB storage engine (default), some space is reserved for the InnoDB redo log.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-redo-log.html

Comment: Make Sense, Thanks @vadim